# When is a multivariable function differentiable?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $$f(x,y)=\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}  & \mbox{if } (x,y) \ne (0,0) \\
   1 & \mbox{if } (x,y)=(0,0)
 \end{array}
\right.$$

I already showed that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. Is it differetiable there? Why?

We've learned about directional derivatives, but as far as I know - the existence of the directional derivatives don't imply that the function is differntiable.

Comment: If all partial derivatives of a function exist and are continuous in a neighborhood of a point, then the function is be differentiable at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the partial derivate are continuous.

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{2x(\cos(x^2+y^2)-\sin(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{2y(\cos(x^2+y^2)-\sin(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)}$$

They are clearly continuous for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$. On $(x,y)=(0,0)$, 
$$\begin{align}\cos(x^2+y^2)-\sin(x^2+y^2)&=\cos(x^2+y^2)-\cos(x^2+y^2-\frac{\pi}{2})\\ &=-2\sin(x^2+y^2+\frac{\pi}{4})\sin(-\frac{\pi}{4})\\ &=\sqrt 2\sin(x^2+y^2+\frac{\pi}{4})\end{align}$$

Then
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x,y)=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{2\sqrt 2r\cos(\theta)\sin(r^2+\frac{\pi}{4})}{r^2} = \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{2\sqrt 2 \cos\theta\sin(r^2+\pi/4)}{r}\to \pm \infty $$

therefore $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is not continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: the converse of the multivariate differentiability theorem is not true. The partials are discontinuous but the function may still be differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

Your $f$ can be written as $f=h\circ g$ with
$$g(x,y):=x^2+y^2, \qquad h(u):={\rm sinc}\, u\ .$$
Both $g$ and $h$ are infinitely differentiable, whence so is $f$.